# Is the "wicked son" of the Haggadah an apostate Jew?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada, christianity, four-sons

I've seen a few sources that seem to understand that the wicked son of the Haggadah was an apostate Jew, who converted to Christianity.  See for example, [this answer and linked article](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36886/16354), as well as [this](https://www.%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2.com/2013/03/Hagada.html).  What other evidence supports or rejects that claim?

Comment: If he's a Rashah what does it matter?

Comment: @AlBerko if he could eat the korbon Pesach